# NGINX site poxy_pass not working for non-www

Tags: nginx

I have a nodejs app (on port:8989) running on nginx  and being routed to port 80.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.access.log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:8989/;
    }
}
```

www. addressess will load the website fine.

My current dns records are the following:

```
A Record     @       108.xxx.xxx.xxx
A Record     www     108.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

This server is running a very old version of nginx. (v0.7)

Comment: Have you checked DNS?

Comment: @AlexeyTen i can tell you what dns says, but i'm not knowledgable enough about dns to know if its wrong. i'll add it to the question

Comment: And what record for `www.example.com`?

Comment: So I wonder, how you could say that `www.example.com` works fine?

Comment: I added the www record back. just to simplify everyone's lives. www still works.